# bxslider is not working with safari

Tags: safari, drupal-7, bxslider

I am using bxslider for vedio with my drupal project. It's working fine with all browser except safari, over here it's showing all videos in single shot.

```
$('.divClass').bxSlider({
  slideWidth: 450,  
  pager:false,      
  video:true,
  useCSS:false
 });
```

my Html code:

```
<div class="divClass">
      <div class="slide">
        <object width="540" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/" id="sb-player1" style="visibility: visible;">
          <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000">
          <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
        </object>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <object width="540" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/" id="sb-player2" style="visibility: visible;">
          <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000">
          <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
        </object>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <object width="540" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/" id="sb-player3" style="visibility: visible;">
          <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000">
          <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
        </object>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Plz help me... What's need for safari, so it can work with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you see all the slides showing at once it means the script isn't loading. Are you seeing anything in console?

Comment: I checked in console also.. No error, I am getting.